# SSL Certificate to body

Tags: ssl-certificate, backend, shopware6

We have SSL Positive certificate for our site.

They say that  we need to add that code of our logo to our site before the `</body>` tag.

I am not a developer or programmer. How can I do this? How can I go to part that I can add this code?

We are using shopware6 last version.

Comment: Why not edit the template you are using, as you would do on any other markup change?

Comment: But how can I edit the template? I dont know anything about this html codes. I am just the admin of the site. Is there a simple step by step instruction for me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a programmers platform, so to add such a HTML code

You can follow this documentation:

https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/customize-templates

If you do not want to program, you might want to try a 3rd party plugin, for example like
https://store.shopware.com/en/media45870525135/custom-html-code.html

Remark: Normally you do not need any HTML code to use a SSL certificate. They might recommend this, but it is technically not needed (if there terms of use require it, you might want to go also with another certificate, such as LetsEncrypt)